# Sending a Post request from a MDL form in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I have a REST API running as my backend server that creates a new entry in the database.
The expected URL to add an entry would be
http://example.com:3002/createclass/:classid/:classname:/bluetoothid
where, classid, classname and bluetoothid are inputs.

On my client side I am trying to take input from the user from a html form.
This is my HTML form relevant code snippets:

```
<form name ="createclass" id="createclass" method="POST" action="#">
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
<input class="mdl-textfield__input" name = "classid" type="text" id="classid" />
<label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="username">Class ID</label>
</div>
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
<input class="mdl-textfield__input" name = "classname" type="text" id="classname" />
<label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="userpass">Class Name</label>
</div>
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
<input class="mdl-textfield__input" name = "bluetoothid" type="text" id="bluetoothid" />
<label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="username">Bluetooth ID</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
<input class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored" type="submit" style="lign-items: center;justify-content: center;">
<i class="material-icons">add</i>
</button>
</form>
```

When I click on the submit button, I want it to send the POST request.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("creatclsbtn").click(function(){
        var MyForm = $("#ajaxform").serializeJSON();
        console.log(MyForm);
        $.ajax(
          {
            url : "http://example.com:3002/createclass",
            type: "POST",
            data : MyForm,
            dataType: json,
            success:function(maindta)
          {
            alert(maindta);
          }
          });
    </script>
```

When I submit this form, Is is the equivalent of doing this?:

```
curl -X POST "http://example.com:3002/createclass/220/Networks/1233"
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: console.log do you get form consoled

Comment: and on html form tag type="submit" you forgot i think so